# Select hierarchical JSON as table in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, hierarchy

I'm trying to select this hierarchical JSON as a table in PostgreSQL

The JSON script:

```
'{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}'
```

[The output I'm trying to get (click this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94It.png)

This is a solution a friend wrote.
It does the required but in a complex way, is there a simpler solution?

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE(SEQ, DESC_D, ID, PARENT_ID, NODES) AS (
  SELECT json_extract_path_text(e.element, 'SEQ') SEQ,
         json_extract_path_text(e.element, 'DESC_D') DESC_D,
         json_extract_path_text(e.element, 'ID') ID,
         NULL PARENT_ID,
         json_extract_path(e.element, 'NODES') NODES
  FROM json_each('{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}'::JSON) a(KEY, val)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(a.val) e(element)
  WHERE json_typeof(a.val) = 'array'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT json_extract_path_text(e.element, 'SEQ') SEQ,
         json_extract_path_text(e.element, 'DESC_D') DESC_D,
         json_extract_path_text(e.element, 'ID') ID,
         r.ID PARENT_ID,
         json_extract_path(e.element, 'NODES') NODES
  FROM CTE r
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(r.NODES) e(element)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID) *
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [jsonpath type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) and [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and [language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       child->>'SEQ' AS seq
     , child->>'DESC_D' AS desc_d
     , child->>'ID' AS id
     , parent->>'ID' AS parent_id
     , child->>'NODES' AS nodes
  FROM jsonb_path_query('{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}'
                       , '$.** ? (@.NODES.type() == "array")') AS parent
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(parent->'NODES') AS child
 ORDER BY seq
```

Result :

| seq | desc_d | id | parent_id | nodes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fam | 2304500 | null | [{"ID": "5214", "SEQ": "2.1", "NODES": [{"ID": "999", "SEQ": "3.1", "DESC_D": "test 1.1"}], "DESC_D": "test 1"}, {"ID": "74542", "SEQ": "2.2", "DESC_D": "test 2"}] |
| 2.1 | test 1 | 5214 | 2304500 | [{"ID": "999", "SEQ": "3.1", "DESC_D": "test 1.1"}] |
| 2.2 | test 2 | 74542 | 2304500 | null |
| 3.1 | test 1.1 | 999 | 5214 | null |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3rxvwuir)

Comment: This answer does not handle nested arrays.

Comment: ??? the result in dbfiddle corresponds to what you expect on your picture, so what is wrong ???

Comment: You know what? You are absolutely right, and I am absolutely wrong. A jsonpath query absolutely does this without need of explicit recursion. My apologies! Looks like I need to brush up on my newer Postgres features and all of the options in jsonpath.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, straightforward for what I was searching for.

Is there a way I can write the code without declaring its column names (or making the naming dynamic) so I can take any JSON with random columns? @Edouard

Comment: Starting from any kind of json structure is not easy, but it is possible to make some parts dynamic, for instance the list of json keys to be transformed into columns. To do so, you can create dynamically a composite type based on the json keys to be displayed as columns and then use the `json_populate_recordset` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74214245/8060017)

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's answer is correct (as is Edouard's). A couple of things could perhaps make the recursive query easier to read. You can use the `->>` operator, which basically executes the json_extract_path_text function. You can also omit the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` because any set-returning function implies that join type when following the `FROM` with a comma. In your case, IDs are unique, so `DISTINCT ON (ID)` isn't needed, but if your JSON *could* have duplicate IDs, you'll need to put it back in.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE(SEQ, DESC_D, ID, PARENT_ID, NODES) AS (
  SELECT e.element ->> 'SEQ' SEQ,
         e.element ->> 'DESC_D' DESC_D,
         e.element ->> 'ID' ID,
         NULL PARENT_ID,
         e.element -> 'NODES' NODES
  FROM json_each('{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}'::JSON) a(KEY, val),
       json_array_elements(a.val) e(element)
  WHERE json_typeof(a.val) = 'array'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.element ->> 'SEQ' SEQ,
         e.element ->> 'DESC_D' DESC_D,
         e.element ->> 'ID' ID,
         r.ID PARENT_ID,
         e.element -> 'NODES' NODES
  FROM CTE r,
       json_array_elements(r.NODES) e(element)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

To make it easier to understand, just remember that the part about `UNION ALL` is always your starting point, and the part after is digging down. Just look at each part separately to help make sense of it.