# Extract attribute columns from hierarchical JSON dynamically - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This query selects a hierarchical JSON as a table in PostgreSQL.
The name of the columns could be hard code as done here, but that's not feasible when working with hundreds of columns.

JSON sample:

```json
{
  "NODES": [
    {
      "DESC_D": "fam",
      "SEQ": "1",
      "ID": "2304500",
      "NODES": [
        {
          "DESC_D": "test 1",
          "SEQ": "2.1",
          "ID": "5214",
          "NODES": [
            {
              "DESC_D": "test 1.1",
              "SEQ": "3.1",
              "ID": "999"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "DESC_D": "test 2",
          "SEQ": "2.2",
          "ID": "74542"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Query sample:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       child->>'SEQ' AS seq
     , child->>'DESC_D' AS desc_d
     , child->>'ID' AS id
     , parent->>'ID' AS parent_id
     , child->>'NODES' AS nodes
  FROM jsonb_path_query('{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}'
                       , '$.** ? (@.NODES.type() == "array")') AS parent
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(parent->'NODES') AS child
 ORDER BY seq
```

I want to get the same output of this code, but without hard coding:

`'SEQ' AS seq`

`'DESC_D' AS desc_d`

`'ID' AS id`

`'NODES' AS nodes`

I need them dynamically written depending on the JSON

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211657/sql-function-to-turn-json-keys-into-attribute-columns) solution but didn't work for me because my JSON is hierarchical (or maybe I didn't implement it the right way).

Comment: Doing this "dynamically" is not possible. One fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of all column of a query must be known to the database _before_ it starts retrieving data.

Comment: you must indicate in your question what result you want to achieve, what do you mean with "I'm trying to have the column declaration (attribute columns) dynamically written" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed solution relies on a composite type which must be dynamically created with the following procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE composite_type (j jsonb) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
  _columns text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT v.key || ' text', ',')
    INTO _columns
  FROM jsonb_path_query( j
                       , '$.** ? (@.NODES.type() == "array")') AS parent
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(parent->'NODES') AS child
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(child) AS v(key, value) ;
 DROP TYPE IF EXISTS composite_type ;
 EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE composite_type AS (' || _columns || ')' ;
END ;
$$ ;
```

First create the composite type :

```
CALL composite_type ('{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}' :: jsonb) ;
```

And then the query :

```
SELECT parent->>'ID' AS parent_id
     , (jsonb_populate_record(null :: composite_type, jsonb_object_agg(lower(v.key), v.value))).*
  FROM jsonb_path_query('{"NODES":[{"DESC_D":"fam","SEQ":"1","ID":"2304500","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1","SEQ":"2.1","ID":"5214","NODES":[{"DESC_D":"test 1.1","SEQ":"3.1","ID":"999"}]},{"DESC_D":"test 2","SEQ":"2.2","ID":"74542"}]}]}'
                       , '$.** ? (@.NODES.type() == "array")') AS parent
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(parent->'NODES') AS child
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(child) AS v(key, value)
 GROUP BY parent, child
 ORDER BY seq
```

provides the expected result :

| parent_id | desc_d | id | nodes | seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | fam | 2304500 | [{"ID": "5214", "SEQ": "2.1", "NODES": [{"ID": "999", "SEQ": "3.1", "DESC_D": "test 1.1"}], "DESC_D": "test 1"}, {"ID": "74542", "SEQ": "2.2", "DESC_D": "test 2"}] | 1 |
| 2304500 | test 1 | 5214 | [{"ID": "999", "SEQ": "3.1", "DESC_D": "test 1.1"}] | 2.1 |
| 2304500 | test 2 | 74542 | null | 2.2 |
| 5214 | test | 1.1 | 999 | null |

Note that in the query `child` is broken down by `CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(child) AS v(key, value)` and then rebuild with `jsonb_object_agg(lower(v.key), v.value)` so that `v.key` are converted into lower cases and correspond to the attribute names of `composite_type` which are necessarily in lower cases.

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bpCYWHsL)